# Permutation Problem on number greater than 30000 and less than 9,999,999 and divisible by 5

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

> Determine how many numbers bigger than 30,000 and smaller than
> 9,999,999 and divisible by 5 can be formed using the digits 0, 1, 2,
> 3, 5, 8 and 9.

The answer is 156,407. Please help on the approach to get this answer!

Thank you.

This is what I have tried:

- total 5 digit numbers possible that will be divisible by 5 $= 2 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$ (unit place on the left)
- total 6 digit numbers possible that will be divisible by $5 = 2\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot6$
- total 7 digit numbers possible that will be divisible by 5 $= 2\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot6$

Then I added all these answers & subtracted those 5 digit numbers lesser than 30,000 and divisible by 5

Then I subtracted 1 (9,999,999 is not to be included).

The answer i get does not match with the one on the book.

Comment: I'm getting the answer of [$233239$](https://tio.run/##RYsxDsIwDEX3nMILSiKhKiWqaIdwl4qmwojGlusOnD6EBf743vv81geVOLLUihuTKKBmUaLXbliwqDP7sbkeVhJAwALuC63tnoTFofd/83t2LLQc95aF/hKHcbJnyZxnTdfW4wp4i6EN5rIAnoaUgje@1g8), is this your answer?

Comment: I am getting 229,466. But answer is supposed to be 156,407

Comment: "*Then I subtracted 1 (9,999,999 is not to be included)*"  Why care about 9,999,999?  That wasn't divisible by five and wasn't among those that you counted... did you mean to say 30,000 here instead?

Comment: You are right. 9,999,999 does not need to be reduced - it anyway is not divisible by 5. 

I got 229,466 as answer and the book as 156,407. I reduced all numbers less than 30,000 divisible by 5 when i counted the total 5-digit numbers divisible by 5. 

Yet, i am not getting anywhere close to the answer.

Comment: I agree with the answer of $233239$ and with the technique described in the post: $2\cdot 7^5\cdot 6 + 2\cdot 7^4\cdot 6 + 2\cdot 7^3\cdot 6 - 2\cdot 2\cdot 7^3 - 1$.  I can only imagine the reason you are not getting $233239$ is due to arithmetic errors.  I do not as of yet see a difference in interpretation of the problem or a changing of some numbers that makes the answer become $156407$

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track.

**5 digits numbers**

We will keep only numbers bigher than $30\ 000$. There is $2$ possibilities for the unit, $7$ for the middle digits and $4$ for the leftmost digit. And we will substract one for $30\ 000$.
$$2\times7\times7\times7\times4-1=2743$$
**6 digits numbers**

You were right there is $2$ possibilities for the unit, $7$ for the middle digits and $6$ for the leftmost digit.
$$2\times7\times7\times7\times7\times6=28812$$
**7 digits numbers**

You were right there is $2$ possibilities for the unit, $7$ for the middle digits and $6$ for the leftmost digit.
$$2\times7\times7\times7\times7\times7\times6=201684$$

Adding those numbers, we find $233\ 239$ possibilities.

There might be a mistake in the book, or there might be something missing in the problem.

Comment: That is really great, then. I will take your solution as final. I am anyway unable to find anything more accurate than this. Alexey and you got the same answers. Thank you very much for the help!